# Admob view set to GONE keeps receiving clicks

Tags: android-layout, view, admob, visibility

Please note : Currently not using any XML for Layout! And I don't want to change that.

I have an Admob banner inflating in my game at a certain point. I used [this](http://rx-games.com/admob-adverts-on-surfaceview-no-xml-tutorial/) tutorial. It's working fine.

Now, when I remove the banner, it disappears as it should. BUT.. it keeps receiving clicks, preventing the underlying view from handeling those clicks. :(

I use this code to remove the ad banner :

```
public static void HideAd() {
    AppelzActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
            animation.setDuration(400);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            AppelzActivity.adView.startAnimation(animation);
            AppelzActivity.adView.setClickable(false);
            AppelzActivity.adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }});
}
```

I would've thought the setClickable(false) and setVisibility(View.GONE) would be sufficient. I also tried setClickable(true), as I found one bugreport about this boolean working the other way around..:S

So, when I call HideAd, the Ad is surely disappearing (AlphaAnimation == working). But then, when I click the region the ad used to be, it still takes me to the URL represented by the ad. I would like that click to be handled by the view that is visible to the user (like it does when I click somewhere outside the region where the banner used to be)..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hm. It worked when I commented out

```
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

Comment: It's possible this happened because with the above line in the code, the animation doesn't persist until after it's over.  But when you try to hide the view, it breaks the animation somehow.

Comment: Ahh.. I understand, Eric.. so you're saying; if I set the view to GONE when I'm sure animation has ended (for instance onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)), it would be no problem.. I'll give it a try. commenting out setFillAfter doesn't bother me, though.. I was under the impression that I needed it, because otherwise the animation end-situation wouldn't be maintained. However, because I'm setting it to GONE, that doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm not actually sure of the behavior; it's just a theory.  But I imagine since you're setting the view to GONE right away, you're not actually getting the animation.